# How to check cache status in ignite

Tags: java, ignite

I need to check cache status using apache ignite. I checked cache metrics as well but it has no method which can show me the status. How will i come to know whether cache is 'active' or not. Can somebody suggest?

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "active" cache? There is no such thing as status for the cache. When you need to use cache, it's enough to understand, was it created or not and create if it wasn't. In this case, you can use method [Ignite.getOrCreateCache](https://ignite.apache.org/releases/latest/javadoc/org/apache/ignite/Ignite.html#getOrCreateCache-java.lang.String-).

Answer (score -1):

You can see the interface Ignite

```
    /**
     * Checks Ignite grid is active or not active.
     *
     * @return {@code True} if grid is active. {@code False} If grid is not active.
     */
    public boolean active();
```

Update:

The comment's right, here is to check ignite cluster'a activity, there's no default method to check a cache instance, but you can create a method like what I did below to check whether you could retrieve something, regardless it's null or not. If the cache is hung, there should be a timeout, you can throw error or log or just return false;

```
    public boolean isResponsive(K key) {
        try {
            CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> cache.get(key)).get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("no response from ignite cache: " + e.getMessage());
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: That function is deprecated and would not help answer the question. That is only for checking the status of the entire cluster. @Evgenii's answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/49852744/5987669) is much more applicable.

Comment: @Locke Yes, I know that. The java doc had said it's about ignite grid. I added my own method to check, this should work.